# Как создать зависимость между компонентами в Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов. Например:

```
var workers = [
    {
        name: 'Ivan',
        age: '23',
        key: '123xfhu44321'
    },
    {
        name: 'Petr',
        age: '31',
        key: '213i2391kkm2'
    },
    {
        name: 'Semen',
        age: '29',
        key: 'oOgjejIeu231'
    }]
```

У меня есть 3 компонента: выпадающий список и два инпута. В выпадающем списке я хотел бы отображать имена работников. И чтобы при выборе конкретного имени работника, инпуты заполнялись значениями из объекта. Например, выбрав Ивана, один инпут заполняется значениеv 23, а другой - ключом: 123xfhu44321.

Если перебирать массив, то это нужно делать в какой-то функции, которую нужно привязать как обработчик некого события компонента. Но ведь мне нужно отображать данные сразу, без каких-либо событий.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Спасибо :)

Comment: чистый яваскрипт только?

Comment: Да, желательно без сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но ведь мне нужно отображать данные сразу, без каких-либо событий.

Вы без события все равно ни как не справитесь

```
var workers; // ваш массив работников и допустим, он постоянен
var select, // ваш select
    input1, input2; // ваши Input-ы

function changeHandler (e) {
    var value = e.value; // значение select-a
    var worker = workers[value]; // получаем индекс работника

    input1.value = worker.age;
    input2.value = worker.key;
}

select.onchange = changeHandler;
```

А в `select-e` в атрибуте `value` поставьте соответствующие индексы для работников

Answer (score 0):

На всякий пожарный

```js
$(function() {
  var workers = [{
    name: 'Ivan',
    age: '23',
    key: '123xfhu44321'
  }, {
    name: 'Petr',
    age: '31',
    key: '213i2391kkm2'
  }, {
    name: 'Semen',
    age: '29',
    key: 'oOgjejIeu231'
  }];

  for (var i = 0, length1 = workers.length; i < length1; i++) {
    console.log(workers[i]);
    $('#sel').append('<option>' + workers[i].name + '</option>');
  }

  $('#sel').on('change', function(event) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
    for (var key in workers) {
      if (workers[key].name == val) {
        $('#age').val(workers[key].age);
        $('#key').val(workers[key].key);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="sel">
  <option selected="">Выберите</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="age">
<input type="text" id="key">
```